# Flask Interactive Debugger Broken

Tags: python, debugging, flask

I'm trying to figure out why the Flask interactive debugger isn't working. My template application is barebones, with a single error:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print missing_variable #Error
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

But the debugger catches the error, but gives me a non-interactive page and complains about a lack of Javascript:

> The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error. If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the exceptions and much more.

I haven't disabled Javascript, so I'm not sure why this the interactive debugger is broken. Thanks!

Edit: I'm running this on a remote host and viewing this over an SSH tunnel. Is it possible that Javascript is disabled in this way?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (except for the extra `.` at the end of `0.0.0.0`.) What browser, version of Flask, version of python, and OS are you on?

Comment: Yes, this baffles me. I've tried the stable versions of Firefox, Chrome, without extensions, on OSX 10.8.4. @korylprince

Comment: Same story here: I can run this fine once the period is fixed. What does the HTML source that you receive look like?

Comment: @MarkHildreth I've uploaded the debugger HTML here: http://pastebin.com/EcM13QPm

Comment: Try requesting http://host/?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js - I would assume something is going wrong with that request.

Comment: Is there anything in the javascript console? F12?

Comment: The output you've supplied is exactly the same as the output that I get in my test console. I would recommend taking out the SSH tunnel and seeing if you can reproduce the issue. If you can't, it's the tunnel. Otherwise, it's something with your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that none of the static files provided by the debugger as part of the Werkzeug suite were being found. Simply uninstalling/reinstalling Flask and Werkzeug fixed this issue. Thanks for everyone who answered!

Comment: For others arriving to this question. If you have `flask` and `werkzeug` installed via `conda`, *this* is the reason for the interactive debugger not working! Simply reinstall those packages via `pip`, and you should be sorted. Via this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978000/flask-debug-not-working-under-anaconda

Answer (score 0):

you're running on 0.0.0.0.
take out the last period

Comment: Good catch! The period was just a copy and paste error; the real problem of not having the interactive debugger still remains.