# Flask debug not working under Anaconda

Tags: python, flask, anaconda

I'm working in a standard development environment with Flask and am having trouble getting the debug to work.

Just using the standard Hello World, with an error like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    err
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My application breaks, but there is no dynamic debugging and I get the following error message:

```
If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code 
execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the 
exceptions and much more.
```

I have JavaScript enabled, and don't know why I'm receiving this error.  Any ideas?

## EDIT

I found this similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805376/flask-interactive-debugger-broken).  It appears that Flask can't find a few files.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2014 22:04:37] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I am using Anaconda and have removed and reinstalled both Flask and Werzeug, but am still having the issue.

Comment: I get the interactive debugger when running your code. I don't use anaconda, though, so I'm guessing it (Anaconda) isn't properly handling the static assets that ship with Werkzeug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also uninstall the conda packages

```
conda remove flask
conda remove werkzeug
```

Then just pip install both of those

```
pip install flask
pip install werkzeug
```

That worked for me using conda 3.4.2

Answer (score 2):

The above comment by [dirn Feb 24 at 3:35](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn) is correct. However, with anaconda, uninstalling and reinstalling packages does not help. Here is a hack that got mine to work...

The `werkzeug/debug` directory on my anaconda installation is missing a directory called `shared`. I have a non-anaconda installation of flask (using macports in my case). I simply copied that directory from my macports installation to the anaconda installation. The command for this with full path names that I used for my `flasky` conda virtual environment was:

```
cp -r /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/shared  ~/anaconda/envs/flasky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug
```

You need to do this separately for each conda virtual environment. Your path names may vary. Also, you should probably ensure that the non-anaconda installation is the same version of werkzeug.