# Flask Debugger Not Running on Mac

Tags: python, flask

I am running the following code with `app.run(debug=True)` on a mac. I am able to run the code and test the application when `debug=False`, but when I try with `debug=True`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 186, in execfile
    exec(compiler(f.read(), fname, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "/flaskhello.py", line 42, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 5004, debug = True)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

  File "/Users/DGS-Mkt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 737, in run_simple
    reloader_type)

  File "/Users/DGS-Mkt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 265, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())

SystemExit: 1
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
questions = ['Is it compiled?', 'Does it run on a VM?']
guesses = ['Python', 'Java', 'C++']


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/question/<int:id>')
def question(id):
    return render_template('question.html', question=questions[id])


@app.route('/guess/<int:id>')
def guess(id):
    return render_template('guess.html', guess=guesses[id])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not running flask on mac. Maybe you have some problems in anaconda. 2 solutions which I suggest to you:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

or you can uninstall packages from anaconda

```
conda remove flask
conda remove werkzeug
```

and install with pip

```
pip install flask
pip install werkzeug
```

source: [Flask debug not working under Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978000/flask-debug-not-working-under-anaconda)