# How to make firefox display the last version of a flask website?

Tags: firefox, flask, web-deployment

I am using a small web server for some project, and I used the classical html-css-javascript combination, with a Flask python server.

I do frequent changes to every parts of the project, saving them each time.
However it happens frequently that what is displayed when looking at the website corresponds to an old version of the project.
For example, if I run the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('indexfake.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

where "indexfake.html" doesn't exists, and then go to http://localhost:5001/, Firefox shows a normal page, which corresponds to the one I normally use.

If I create templates/indexfake.html (for example:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<body><p>a</p>
    <script>
console.log('smthng');
    </script>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

The JS part is correctly executed (only if the old version had a `<script>` section) but the html still corresponds to the old version. However if I copy the old version pattern but with modifying it a bit, the modifications appear in the navigator

I tried to manually clean the cache (I am using Firefox), but it doesn't change anything. I tried to stop and re-run the server too, same non-results.

The bug is not consistent, and usually it ends after something like an hour, but currently I am experiencing it since more than 24 hours.

Do someone know what is happening and how to fix it ?

As a complement, here is the encapsulating template I use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Cool App</title>
<div class=page>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
    </head>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</html>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805376/flask-interactive-debugger-broken#) seems similar but the answer asked (reinstalling Flask and the Werkzeug suite) haven't worked for me.

Comment: Can you show an example of your html templates?

Comment: I can't show a minimal example which reproduces the bug, since it not consistently happening, but I added the "header" template. Is that enough ?

Comment: What I want to know is just the way you use html templates. Are you using Jinja2 template?

Comment: I use it through Flask, yes.

Comment: Update `rel` and `type` attributes in your link tags (`rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`) and make sure that all your static files are directly under `static/` folder.

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126529/discussion-between-anne-aunyme-and-ettanany).

Comment: Does opening the page in a new private session make the problem go away? If so, it's probably a caching problem.

Comment: @sytech: No, but it makes the code readable from the debugger different (but still not the last version)