# How to enable javascript on Flask Interactive Debugger in chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, flask, pycharm

My code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/username/<name>/<int:age>")
def hello(name, age):
    return f"<p>Welcome {name + 12}, you are {age} years old?</p>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I triggered a `TypeError` on purpose while following a tutorial on udemy in order to access the Flask interactive debugger using Chrome but I keep getting this message whenever I try to use the debug console to access the "name" or "age" variable like so:

```
[console ready] 
>>> name
```

The message I get:

> The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application.  You can now
> look at the traceback which led to the error.
> If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code
> execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the
> exceptions and much more.

My javascript is not disabled on chrome and I tried the solution suggested here by uninstalling and reinstalling Flask/Werkzeug but it is still not working: [Flask Interactive Debugger Broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805376/flask-interactive-debugger-broken)

Please, How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The message is saying it is in Debug mode. If you scroll above the error message in the browser, and also see in the console where you launched the app, it should still output Traceback with TypeError pointing to the exact error: `return f"<p>Welcome {name + 12}, you are {age} years old?</p>"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. 
    
 Is this still not solving your problem?

Comment: Hello @davedwards , thank you so much for replying. Sadly No, it does not. I have been trying to access the flask debugger from Chrome and I always get the above message about enabling javascript after inputting the pin: "... if you enable javascript, you can also use additional features ...". Although, when I access my application using Firefox and try to use the debugger, it works fine.

Comment: So you just want to disable to the above error message from chrome debugging?

Comment: Yes @davedwards